# how I can get the members of a LDAP Dynamic group using Java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

we required to fetch all user of dynamic group from LDAP server in Our Java based application.
below is my dynamic group url:

```
ldap:///ou=testou,o=test.com??sub?(&(|(atype=*Abc Company*)(atype=*def Company*)(ctype=test))(enabled=1)(!(sgroup=*testgrp*))(!(|(op=ABC)(bdesc=*abcdef*))))
```

when i provided filter from above url in JXplore, i am able to get user group which is available in this dynamic group but when i provide same filter in below java code LDAP is not returning any result. If i provided simple filter like cn=a* then it is working and LDAP is returning results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException, IOException {
     Properties env = new Properties();
     env.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
           "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
     // LDAP url
     env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "url");
     env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "1000");
     // ldap login
     env.put("java.naming.security.principal", "username");
     env.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "password");
     InitialLdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
     String contextName = "ou=testou,o=test.com";
     // Filter expression
     String filterExpr = "(&(|(atype=*Abc Company*)(atype=*def Company*)(ctype=test))(enabled=1)(!(sgroup=*testgrp*))(!(|(op=ABC)(bdesc=*abcdef*))))"; // selects the groups a user belongs to.


     SearchControls constraints = new javax.naming.directory.SearchControls();
     constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE); // SUBTREE_SCOPE means recursive search
     ctx.setRequestControls(new Control[]{new PagedResultsControl(1000,true)});
     byte[] cookie = null;
     int totalResults = 0;


     NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> search = ctx.search(contextName,
           filterExpr,constraints);
     int count=0;
     while (search.hasMoreElements()) {
      count++;
        System.out.println(search.next().getName());    
    }
     System.out.println("Total user"+count);
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you tried and why does it not work?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have added code which i have tried.@jwilleke

Comment: Your query makes no sense. Are you implying you really have attributes defined with names aType, cType, bdesc, sgroup and op?

Comment: yes, in LDAP we can configured custom property or let considered all are stranded property and i have changed name while posting question.@jwilleke

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about JNDI, sadly the [JNDI Tutorial, p. 247](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/misc/url.html), says:

> Note: Version 1.2 of Sun's LDAP provider does not treat query components properly

and nothing appears to have changed in any release up to Java 8.

The Dynamic Groups feature relies on this.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer or please add reference link. Thanks !

Comment: I have already told you that it doesn't work. What else exactly do you want me to say?

Comment: i am not passing filter in URL and passing filter as filter in search method, you can see that in my code, i have go thought documentation and it specified that if we passed as URL then its not supported. and Thanks for down vote my question without reading my code. @EJP

Comment: I read your code; I understand how the Dynamic Groups feature works; I understand that it relies on query components in the URL in the entry; I know that that Java doesn't support that properly; and I said so; and I provided a citation. I still don't know what more you could possibly ask for. NB You have no information about who downvoted your question. It's a secret ballot.

Comment: I am able to get dynamic user using filter URL but LDAP return only random number of user and also throwing below error:

`[LDAP: error code 11 - LDAP Error 11 : [LDAP: error code 11 - This search operation has checked the maximum of 5000 entries for matches]];`

i have set below in context:
`NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("ldap:///ou=testou,o=test.com??sub?(&(|(atype=*Abc Company*)(atype=*def Company*)(ctype=test))(enabled=1)(!(sgroup=*testgrp*))(!(|(op=ABC)(bdesc=*abcdef*))))", "", searchCtls);` @EJP